# Using Relay and contactless water level sensor to switch on or off motor pump

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, motors, control-theory, sensors

I have no prior experience related to electrical projects and I am having confusion about which type of relay and how to connect relay, contactless water level sensor and motor pump.

So basically I have a DC-DC converter that has output of 6A and converts 12 V to 24 V. And the 24 V motor pump that draws 6A at 60 PSI (42.2 metres of head). I am using this Iduino TC-9520284 Sensor-Module (Operating Voltage of 4.8 to 24 V DC and operating current <= 5 mA).

So I need a 24 V relay and current rating greater than or equal to 6 A is what I know. To have the relay and sensor setup between the load (motor pump) and DC-DC converter...the relay I have chosen is Omron G5LE-1A relay.

Could you please let me know if this relay suitable for this application and few tips about how may I start figuring how to connect them?

Comment: the pump will probably require a lot more than 6 A to start up